# In keras(deep learning library), sush custom embedding layer possible?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I just moved in recently from theano, lasagne to keras.

When I in theano, I used such custom embedding layer.

[How to keep the weight value to zero in a particular location using theano or lasagne?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501853/how-to-keep-the-weight-value-to-zero-in-a-particular-location-using-theano-or-la)

It' was useful when deal of variable length input by adding padding.

In keras, such custom embedding layer possible? 
Then, how can I make it?

And, such embedding layer may be wrong?

Comment: In case you did not find the documentation, here is how keras.io says about writing your own layer: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want, but the solution I personally use as it is used in Keras examples (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py)) is to pad the data to a constant length before feeding it to network.

Keras itself provide this pre-processing tool for sequences in `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(seq, length)`

Comment: This is not exact solution for I was looking for.
But, I think this will be a clue. Thanks!